# Laravel ambiguous key in 'where' clause

Tags: laravel

I have a customer class and a pet class which has a many to many relationship. There is a pivot table `customer_pet`. Both the `customers` table and the `pets` table have a `team_id`.

When I write the following code:

```
$results = auth()->user()->team->customers();
$results->leftJoin('customer_pet', 'customer_pet.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id');
$results->leftJoin('pets', 'pets.id', '=', 'customer_pet.pet_id');
return $results->get()->load('pets');
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'team_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `customers` left join `customer_pet` on `customer_pet`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` left join `pets` on `pets`.`id` = `customer_pet`.`pet_id` where `customers`.`team_id` = 2 and `customers`.`team_id` is not null and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null and `team_id` = 2
```

I tried making the relation in the `Customer` model look like this:

```
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'customers.team_id', 'teams.id');
    }
```

but I get the same result. I am missing something obvious but I am not sure what?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select * from `customers` left join `customer_pet` on `customer_pet`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` left join `pets` on `pets`.`id` = `customer_pet`.`pet_id` where `customers`.`team_id` = 2 and `customers`.`team_id` is not null and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null and `team_id` = 2
```

The query in the exception shows that there is a `team_id = 2` at the end. It seems that you're adding a `$query->where('team_id', 2)` without qualification somewhere in your code.

You can use `$query->qualifyColumn($column)` to prepend the table name automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I am an idiot - I thought the team_id was coming from the auth()->user()->team->customers() part!